# Java process stays open

Tags: java, process

I like playing Minecraft but after I close Minecraft, the java process stays on and I need to go into the system monitor to kill it or else there will be a lot of java processes on slowing down my game.
How do I get the java processes to end after I close Minecraft?

Comment: It should end by itself. Are you sure you have the last version of Java and Minecraft ?

Comment: have you updated your jdk and jre??

Comment: I have the latest minecraft launcher version and I think I'm using the latest java. I use OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime. I don't know about jre though.